# Using 'LoadPercentage' for performance monitoring

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the value retrieved from the WMI-Object to set a criteria for performance monitoring.

Here are the codes that I have used:

```
$CPULoad = Get-WMIObject -computername $computer win32_processor | `
           Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | `
           Select Average

$WarningCPU = ($CPULoad * 0.8)

If ($CPULoad -ge $WarningCPU){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("CPU Usage is over 80%","Warning","Ok","Warning")
}
```

I want to keep the cpu usage at a limit of 80% by using these codes, however this came up:

> *Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Multiply'.*
>
> *Cannot compare "@{Average=14}" to "50" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{Average=14}" does not implement "IComparable".*

Is there a way to make the values "comparable" so that the messagebox will show up when cpu usage of user hits >80% ?

Comment: Use `... | Select -ExpandProperty Average`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @arco444 said, use `| Select -ExpandProperty Average` to solve your problem. This will make your error go away.

I just want to expand on the issue and the importance of types.

### Types

The problem you are having in your code is that the `Average` property that you get back from `Measure-Object` is not a "number". It looks like one, but the type is not something you can use for calculations.

Remember, PowerShell cmdlets return objects and place them in the pipeline. They might look like numbers and text, but might be something entirely different.

You can check the properties and types of what PowerShell cmdlets return by piping their result through the cmdlet `Get-Member`, or if you prefer its alias `gm`.

Running

```
Get-WMIObject -computername $computer win32_processor | `
           Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | `
           Select Average | `
           Get-Member
```

will tell you that Average has type

```
TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo
```

`GenericMeasureInfo` can't be used calculations.

However, it will tell you there is a property named `Average` of type double.

Double is good, that you can use for calculations :)

### Extracting properties using Select-Object -ExpandProperty

Problem now is that it must be extracted from the object. This is where `Select -ExpandObject` comes into play.

It takes a property and extracts it from the parent object, preserving its type.

Running

```
Get-WMIObject -computername $computer win32_processor | `
           Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | `
           Select -ExpandProperty Average | `
           Get-Member
```

tells you the type now is

```
TypeName: System.Double
```

Now calculations work :)

Comment: Hello Kim, found couple of issues in your code blocks ;)
1. Both blocks introduced by Running are identical, while I believe the secondary block should be rather utilizing ExpandProperty parameter
2. There is no WMI class like Win32_Procesor, but Win32_Processor ;)

Comment: Thanks! Fixed those issue. Also, edited the original question since the same mistake was there as well. Rewrote parts of my answer to address your second point.